# How to organize my HTML and CSS better?

Tags: html, css

I am in the learning of coding so I'm very new to this. But I'm pretty sure I could set up my code a much better way than i have done, could anyone tell me what I can do better? Reason for asking is to be better on it.

HTML Code:

```
 <div class="infobox">
 <a href="https://opskins.com/?loc=shop_search&sort=lh&app=433850_1&search_item=%22Skin%3A+Pinstripe+Suit+Jacket%22"><h3>Pinstripe Suit Jacket</h3></a>
      <div class="suggested">
          <div class="sug-text">
             <h4 class="opskinsug">OPSkins Suggested:</h4>
             <h4 class="survivorsug">Survivor's Suggested:</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="sug-price">
             <h4 class="opssug">$0.26</h4>
             <h4 class="survsug">$0.27</h4>
          </div>

     </div>


     <div class="cheap" id="pinstripe-jacket">
        <p> 44</p>
     </div>

 <img src="images/pinstripesuitjacket.png" width="300" >

 </div>
```

CSS Code:

```
.infobox {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: orange;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.infobox a:link {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}



.infobox a:visited {
    color: #fff;
}

.infobox a:hover {
    color: black;
}

.infobox h3 {
    background-color: orange;
}

.infobox img {
      position: relative;
      top: -232px;
      left: 15px;
      z-index: 0;
}

.opskinsug {
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100px;
    position: relative;
    left: -20px;
    z-index: 1;
    display: inline-block;
}

.survivorsug {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    left: 20px;
    font-size: 13px;
    width: 100px;
    z-index: 1;
    display: inline-block;
}

.opssug {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100px;
    left: -20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    top: -40px;
    z-index: 1;
    display: inline-block;
}

.survsug {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    font-size: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    top: -40px;
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 1;
    display: inline-block;
}

.suggested {
    background-color: rgba(255, 165, 0, 0.4);
    height: 70px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;

}

.sug-text {
    position: relative;
    top: -5px;
}

.sug-price {
    position: relative;
    top: -8px;
}

.cheap {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    font-size: 52px;
    display: inline-block;
    left: -70px;
    color: #fff;
}
```

on my screen its looking like this:
[preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFYYg.png)

Comment: While I'm not entirely sure what you want to achieve, or what your question really is, I'm pretty sure the data you provided belongs in a `<table>`, not `<div>`s

Comment: what i want to achieve is to be better on it, this is just a project im doing to learn more. And like in the class you ask the teacher what you can do better, so i just want to know what i can do better if anybody can take time to tell me. Because i dont understand so much about it at this time, but i understand that i could have done it alot better! Look at the picture i added, thats how it is and i want it to be, just want to do it correct and better organized! :)

Comment: I posted an answer with updated HTML (no CSS) - take a look and see if you can manage to rewrite the CSS to fit.

Comment: Welcome! Please: [ask] | [mcve] | [help].

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would be better on the Code Review site.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an updated HTML. I've replaced the inner `<div>`s with a definition list `<dl>`, which isn't entirely meant for this use, but since you're having 1 on 1 relationship with heading and price, it can be used for this. I also removed the `<p>` inside the last `<div>`, since that is not a paragraph in any way, and you can position it inside the `<div>` (no need for a wrapper, really). I didn't do the CSS, but it should be fairly simple to reformat it to fit the new HTML.

```html
<div class="infobox">
 <a href="https://opskins.com/?loc=shop_search&sort=lh&app=433850_1&search_item=%22Skin%3A+Pinstripe+Suit+Jacket%22"><h3>Pinstripe Suit Jacket</h3></a>
      <div class="suggested">
          <dl>
             <dt>OPSkins Suggested:</dt>
             <dd>$0.26</dd>
          </dl>
          <dl>
             <dt>Survivor's Suggested:</dt>
             <dd>$0.27</dd>
          </dl>
      </div>
      <div class="cheap" id="pinstripe-jacket">
        44
     </div>
     <img src="images/pinstripesuitjacket.png" width="300">
 </div>
```